# How to compute total covariance matrix from two separated datasets x and y

Tags: statistics, covariance

I have two datasets x (mxn) and y (mxq). Where m are the features that are shared by both datasets and n, q the samples that are different.

I want to find a way to compute the covariance matrix as if the two datasets were bind by columns and not separated.

Let D be the resultant matrix from binding columns of x with columns of y and with dimension m x (n+q)):

\begin{bmatrix}x&y\end{bmatrix}

Due to privacy issues I can't merge x and y together to obtain D matrix, furthermore I cannot use a function that asks as input both x and y.

One possible solution is to compute the cov(D) matrix from the cov(x) and cov(y) as block matrix in the form:

\begin{bmatrix}cov(x)&cov(x,y)\\cov(y,x)&cov(y)\end{bmatrix}

The problem with this solution is that the cov(x,y) cannot be obtained without knowing original x and y datasets.

Summing up I want to know if there is a way to build cov(D) from a function taking in input cov(x) and cov(y) but not cov(x,y).

Hope to be clear

Comment: Well, if you look up the definition of the sample covariance you can convince yourself quite easily that this is not possible without having both data in one place. Check out ‘differential privacy’ for a mathematical rigorous way of retaining privacy guarantees in the process of data analytics. Link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_privacy

Comment: ok, thank you for the answer. I change my question in the general problem I need to solve right now.

Answer (score 1):

Covariance depends not merely on the variance of the individual input sets but also the order they appear in.  If it is always true that $x_a > x_b$ implies $y_a > y_b$, then the covariance reaches a maximum; if on the other hand $x_a > x_b$ implies the opposite, that $y_a < y_b$, then the covariance is exactly the negative that of the first case.  Other orders produce a whole range of values in between.

As a visual example, here are three data sets, using values from $-4$ to $4$ for both $x$ and $y$.  in the first, $x_a = y_a$ so the covariance is as positive as possible, $20/3$, which is equal to the variance of each of the two input sets; in the second, $x_a = -y_a$ so the covariance is as negative as possible, $-20/3$; in the third, the permutation is shuffled in a way that gives a covariance of exactly $0$.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I don't get how this comment answers my question

Comment: In short: you're boned.  If you can't see them both at once, you can't calculate the covariance.  On the other hand this kind of thing is so useful that I can't imagine you wouldn't be able to ask your data provider for covariances directly.

Comment: The think is that x and y datasets came from 2 different providers, and because of privacy issues one provider cannot send the data to the other